# Number Normalization for Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, locale, number-formatting

I'm trying to normalize a number from a form, which will/could be in the local number format. e.g.

```
Locale:en-US
1,234.56 -> 1234.56

Locale:nl-NL
1.234,56 -> 1234.56
```

Is there an equivalent in ZF2 to the ZF1 `Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber`?

Thanks in advance

Aborgrove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like the [numberFormat](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/I18n/Filter/NumberFormat.php) Filter?

Comment: d'oh! yes just like that. Thanks Rufinus, sometimes I can't see the wood through the trees.

Comment: Actually Rufinus, could you give me an example of the conversion code from a local number e.g. 1,200,500.00 to 1200500.00 with a locale of en_US?

Comment: take a look at 
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/tests/ZendTest/I18n/Filter/NumberFormatTest.php#L77