# Zend framework 2 form element normalization

Tags: forms, zend-framework, locale, normalization

I am migrating an application from Zend 1 to Zend 2 and starting to desperate with one issue. The application works with different locales and therefore, I need to store the data in a normalized way in the database. In Zend 1 I used this code:

```
public function normalizeNumber( $value ) 
{
    // get the locale to change the date format
    $this->_locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale' );    
    return Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber($value, array('precision' => 2, 'locale' => $this->_locale));
}
```

Unfortunately Zend 2 does not has this **Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber** any more and I was not able to figure out what function did replace it. I have tried with NumberFormat, but I get only localized data not normalized. I need this function to normalize data I receive from a form via POST. Can someone give some advice?

thanks

Just to complete my question. The Form element definition I am using is the following:

```
namespace Profile\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class Profile Extends Form  implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct( $model, $name = 'assignmentprofile')
    {
        parent::__construct( $name );
        $this->setAttribute( 'method', 'post');

        $this->model = $model;

        ...

        $this->add( array(
            'name' =>'CommutingRate',
            'type' =>'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'options' => array( // list of options to add to the element
                'label' => 'Commuting rate to be charged:',
                'pattern' => '/[0-9.,]/',

            ),
            'attributes' => array( // Attributes to be passed to the HTML lement
                'type' =>'text',
                'required' => 'required',
                'placeholder' => '',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
        ...

        'CommutingRate' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array(  'name' => 'StripTags', ),
                array(  'name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array( 'name' => 'NumberFormat', 'options' => array('locale' => 'en_US', 'style' => 'NumberFormatter::DECIMAL', 'type' => 'NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE',
                ))
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(  'name' => 'Float',
                    'options' => array( 'messages' => array('notFloat' => 'A valid numeric entry is required')),
                ),
            ),),

        ...

        );    
    }
}
```

As mentioned before, I am able to localized the data and validate it in the localized manner, but i am failing to convert it back to a normalized manner...

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595260/number-normalization-for-zend-framework-2) suggests to use the [NumberFormat](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.i18n.filter.number.format.html) filter.

Comment: I used the following InputFilterSpecification:             'CommutingRate' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array( 'name' => 'NumberFormat', 'options' => array('locale' => 'en_US', 'style' => 'NumberFormatter::DECIMAL', 'type' => 'NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE',
                    ))
                ),
                ),
However I still get 0,6 as a form value instead of 0.6, So what I am doing wrong?